# MacBook Pro 2017 Geekbench Before and After Spectre and Meltdown Patch

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, performance

I was just wanting to see the impact on speed due to the patches for the recent [Intel CPU Bugs](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/7o39et/meltdown_spectre_megathread/).

I have run the update already, but was wondering if someone could run a Geekbench test on macOS 10.13.1 and 10.13.2 for a by-the-numbers comparison to how the CPU ran before and after the update (preferably on a 15” 2017 machine)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Meltdown & Spectre bug & new CPU's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311282/meltdown-spectre-bug-new-cpus?rq=1), but could be similar in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Industry testing is/has already been done and will continue as this issue is flushed out.   According to a just released press release directly from Intel, [Industry Testing Shows Recently Released Security Updates Not Impacting Performance in Real-World Deployments](https://newsroom.intel.com/news-releases/industry-testing-shows-recently-released-security-updates-not-impacting-performance-real-world-deployments/), the following OEMs/Manufactures have stated the following:

> Apple: “Our testing with public benchmarks has shown that the changes
>   in the December 2017 updates **resulted in no measurable reduction in
>   the performance of macOS and iOS as measured by the GeekBench 4
>   benchmark, or in common Web browsing benchmarks such as Speedometer,
>   JetStream, and ARES-6.**”
>
> Microsoft: “The majority of Azure customers should not see a noticeable performance impact with this update. We’ve worked to
>   optimize the CPU and disk I/O path and are not seeing noticeable
>   performance impact after the fix has been applied.”
>
> Amazon: “We have not observed meaningful performance impact for the overwhelming majority of EC2 workloads.”
>
> Google: “On most of our workloads, including our cloud infrastructure, we see negligible impact on performance.”

[Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208394) also goes on to further expand on the testing stating that:

> Our current testing indicates that the upcoming Safari mitigations
>   will have no measurable impact on the Speedometer and ARES-6 tests and
>   an impact of less than 2.5% on the JetStream benchmark.